# Cubic Power of Supercovariant Derivative

Tags: homework-and-exercises, supersymmetry

Let $\bar{D}_{\dot{\alpha}}=\bar{\partial}_{\dot{\alpha}}-i(\bar{\sigma}^{\mu})_{\dot{\alpha}\beta}\theta^{\theta}\partial_{\mu}$ be the supercovariant derivative. How to prove the following identity?

$$\bar{D}_{\dot{\alpha}}\bar{D}^{2}\equiv0$$

where $\bar{D}^{2}=\bar{D}^{\dot{\beta}}\bar{D}_{\dot{\beta}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. One of the covariant derivatives in $\bar{D}^{2}$ must be $\bar{D}_{\dot{\alpha}}$.
2. A Covariant derivative squares to zero.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hints！